# Where I can find My Lists in the recent Foursquare v8 app?

Tags: iphone

After recent upgrade of Foursquare app (v8.0.2), all my [Lists](https://support.foursquare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201104950-Lists) disappeared, so I can't find any method of accessing them from the iPhone app (I can still see them when accessing from the website).

Does it mean it's a bug, feature or managing of the lists are now no longer supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked the [support](https://support.foursquare.com/) and I've received the following answer:

> Currently you can save to your to-do list on the Foursquare app.
>   Saving to other lists should be coming soon. Your lists are available
>   if you visit Foursquare and navigate to Profile > Saved Places. See
>   you existing lists by tapping on "See all of your saved lists."
>
> To add to your list, simply go to a listing on Foursquare and hit
>   “Save." To remove, simple tap "Save" again. Keep in mind lists are
>   viewable to the public.
>
> To learn more about lists and how you can use them on Foursquare check
>   out this article:
>   https://support.foursquare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201104950-Lists